# Return min and max key and value pair from hash of arrays in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

If I try to repeat all objects I will do it like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="expense in allExpenses">
    <span>{{expense.name}}</span>
    <span>{{expense.price}}</span>
</li>
```

but how to return only min and max pair?

```
0: { name: "a", price: 25 }
1: { name: "b", price: 50 }
2: { name: "c", price: 15 }
```

I need to get name:b price: 50 for Max, and name:c price:15 for Min.
Any ideas?

Comment: Add a minExpense() function and a maxExpense() function to your scope, and call them from your view. So, in short, finding the min and the max is not something that the job should do, but something that the controller should do.

Comment: Could you give me example?

Comment: this is what you need!  http://underscorejs.org/#max  and  http://underscorejs.org/#min

Comment: Finding the max element of an array is probably the very first algorithm you write when learning loops. You should be able to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: i was hoping to get some function (like underscore has) instead of looping and comparing values by myself

Comment: @MilanČančarević it's a really simple loop. If you want to work with angular is better to spend the time now to learn how to do this. Other libraries are helpful but if you aren't able to do simple ones like this you will forever struggle using angular